Camera Orientation Not Changing in iOS app
I'm writing an iOS app that uses the camera. The camera works fine when it is in portrait mode, but when I rotate my phone to landscape mode, the camera doesn't show properly.
In portait mode, the camera shows as expected. But in landscape mode, the camera comes up sideways and only takes up part of the screen.
Here's the code I've tried so far:
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenRect.size.width, height: screenRect.size.height)
        
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
            // Home button on top
            case UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown:
                self.previewLayer.connection?.videoRotationAngle = 180
                
            // Home button on right
            case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:
                self.previewLayer.connection?.videoRotationAngle = 180
                
            // Home button on left
            case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:
                self.previewLayer.connection?.videoRotationAngle = -180
            
            // Home button at bottom
            case UIDeviceOrientation.portrait:
                self.previewLayer.connection?.videoRotationAngle = 0
                
            default:
                break
        }
    }

Thank you in advance for the help!

Orientation always starts from landscapeLeft (0°), and from that position you rotate your phone clockwise: portrait (90°), landscapeRight (180°) and portraitUpsideDown (270°)
So try this:
 extension UIDevice {
    var videoRotationAngle: CGFloat {
        switch orientation {
        case .portrait:
            return 90.0
        case .landscapeRight:
            return 180.0
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            return 270.0
        default:
            return 0.0 // no rotation
        }
    }
}
// ...
self.previewLayer.connection?.videoRotationAngle = UIDevice.current.videoRotationAngle

